# Making an API call in a GRUB script to select OS to boot

Tags: boot, grub, grub2

I have a computer with multiple operating systems and GRUB installed. The system is often woken up over LAN using a magic packet, but without someone being physically present, it's not possible to choose which OS to boot. All the solutions I have found thus far involve booting the current default, connecting to that OS, changing the GRUB config from that OS and rebooting. This seems rather tedious since the process of connecting to the machine and changing the config is different across different operating systems and it takes much longer for the target OS to be booted.

However, [it is possible to choose a boot entry depending on the current time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317352/can-grub-be-scheduled-this-means-changing-default-entry-auto-login-at-defi), so I thought it might be possible to use `curl` or another utility to ask another machine which OS to boot. I have another machine on the local network that runs 24/7, has a static IP and is even the one sending the magic packet that I could use for this. I was thinking about an HTTP request but I don't mind if SSH, FTP or any other protocol works better. Security is not a concern either.

**tl;dr**: Is it possible to fetch a remote string or number from another machine from within a GRUB script using any protocol? If not, is there an alternative to GRUB that can do this?

Comment: `curl` is a Linux program and would require the Linux system to be pretty much booted and running prior to being able to run.  Essentially you would boot, check for a config file, download it using curl, apply it and then reboot. Sure you could automate it in a script, but it is essentially the same as connecting to it yourself, just with an "if this file isn't the same as the one I've got then reboot with the new one" step. Grub doesn't seem to have a network module https://www.linux.org/threads/understanding-the-various-grub-modules.11142/ which isn't that suprising as it would need an OS...

Comment: According to that page it does have a tftp module though, which might be able to be used to grab boot files from another system...

Comment: Is it an EFI system? If so you could try an EFI shell script with `ifconfig` and `tftp` or `http` to get remote file - see http://superuser.com/questions/1179084/ddg#1383049